# Laravel queued event listener model query doesn't always run but gracefully errors

Tags: php, laravel, event-handling

I'm working in a Laravel 10 project that's being used as an API for a Nuxt front-end. The project processes thousands of events, most of which are responsible for aggregated reporting purposes. I have three models that I need to update aggregated columns on, these models are:

1. `AffiliateMinutelySummaryStat`
2. `AffiliateHourlySummaryStat`
3. `AffiliateDailySummaryStat`

The migrations for these models are the same across all three apart from my `logged_at` data time column that rounds to the minute, hour and day for each model.

My problem is that my queued event listener `StoreAffiliateSummaryStat` strangely appears to be gracefully stopping execution in unpredictable ways on my `firstOrNew` method.

In my event listener attached, if I log the `$event->value` on the line prior to `firstOrNew` I get the event run all of the time, without fail, as I need it to, and once it's either instantiated or retrieved the model it should then proceed to increment the passed column's value, but it doesn't always get to here, and no errors have been thrown when catching them.

What am I missing?

```php
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Events\AffiliateSummaryStatCreation;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use App\Models\Reports\Minutely\AffiliateMinutelySummaryStat;
use App\Models\Reports\Hourly\AffiliateHourlySummaryStat;
use App\Models\Reports\Daily\AffiliateDailySummaryStat;
use Illuminate\Support\Sleep;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class StoreAffiliateSummaryStat implements ShouldQueue
{
    /**
     * The name of the connection the job should be sent to.
     *
     * @var string|null
     */
    public $connection = 'redis-short-running';

    /**
     * The name of the queue the job should be sent to.
     *
     * @var string|null
     */
    public $queue = 'statistics';

    /**
     * The number of times the queued listener may be attempted.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public $tries = 1;

    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the tags that should be assigned to the job.
     *
     * @return array<int, string>
     */
    public function tags(): array
    {
        return ['affiliateStatistic'];
    }

    /**
     * Create statistics for each model
     */
    protected function createStatistic($model, $event)
    {
        try {
            $modelable = $model['model'];

            Sleep::for(rand(0, 3000))->milliseconds();

             Log::debug('always runs...');

            $summaryStatistic = $modelable::firstOrNew([
                'user_id' => isset($event->userId) && !empty($event->userId) ? $event->userId : null,
                'company_id' => isset($event->companyId) && !empty($event->companyId) ? $event->companyId : null,
                'affiliate_id' => isset($event->affiliateId) && !empty($event->affiliateId) ? $event->affiliateId : null,
                'brand' => isset($event->brand) && !empty($event->brand) ? $event->brand : null,
                'logged_at' => Carbon::parse($event->loggedAt)->format($model['format'])
            ]);

            $field = $event->column;

            Log::debug('sometimes never gets here????');

            $summaryStatistic->$field = $summaryStatistic->$field + $event->value;

            if ($field == 'total_processing_duration') {
                if (
                    $summaryStatistic->total_processing_duration > 0 &&
                    $summaryStatistic->total_leads > 0
                ) {
                    $summaryStatistic->avg_processing_duration = round(
                        $summaryStatistic->total_processing_duration /
                        $summaryStatistic->total_leads
                    );
                }
            }

            if ($field == 'total_processing_accept_duration') {
                if (
                    $summaryStatistic->total_processing_accept_duration > 0 &&
                    $summaryStatistic->total_accepted > 0
                ) {
                    $summaryStatistic->avg_processing_accept_duration = round(
                        $summaryStatistic->total_processing_accept_duration /
                        $summaryStatistic->total_accepted
                    );
                }
            }

            if ($field == 'total_processing_decline_duration') {
                if (
                    $summaryStatistic->total_processing_decline_duration > 0 &&
                    $summaryStatistic->total_declined > 0
                ) {
                    $summaryStatistic->avg_processing_decline_duration = round(
                        $summaryStatistic->total_processing_decline_duration /
                        $summaryStatistic->total_declined
                    );
                }
            }

            $summaryStatistic->save();

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            Log::debug('No errors are thrown');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     */
    public function handle(AffiliateSummaryStatCreation $event): void
    {
        $models = [[
            'model' => 'App\Models\Reports\Minutely\AffiliateMinutelySummaryStat',
            'format' => 'Y-m-d H:i:00'
        ], [
            'model' => 'App\Models\Reports\Hourly\AffiliateHourlySummaryStat',
            'format' => 'Y-m-d H:00:00'
        ], [
            'model' => 'App\Models\Reports\Daily\AffiliateDailySummaryStat',
            'format' => 'Y-m-d 23:59:59'
        ]];

        foreach ($models as $key => $model) {
            $this->createStatistic($model, $event);
        }
    }
}
```

For additional context, I'm using Horizon and Redis. And here's an example of me dispatching a statistic:

```php
AffiliateSummaryStatCreation::dispatch(
    Carbon::now(),
    'total_submits',
    isset($affiliate) ? $affiliate->user_id : null,
    isset($affiliate) ? $affiliate->company_id : null,
    isset($affiliate) ? $affiliate->id : null,
);
```

Comment: How are you sure you have no errros? I know you are using `Log` and everything is inside a `try catch`, but you are not using `\Throwable`, you are using `\Exception`... If you check the Horizon dashboard and search on the failed jobs for this job, do you see an error? It must be erroring out or just timing out. Why do you have a `sleep`? So, based on what you wrote, if you code something like `Log::debug($event->value);` before the `firstOrNew`, it always work 100%? How are you sure?

Comment: I've tried removing the `try/catch` entirely as well, nothing. By removing the wrapping `try/catch` this would allow any error to be thrown if there was, but nothing is being logged.

Comment: As for the `Sleep`, this appears to have a marginal impact on allowing more consistency in saving records between tables. Strange. This should be the same in all.

Comment: I'm sure that it works by logging before `firstOrNew` because I always see my `Log::debug('always runs...');`